# Extract and format the time

Tags: c#, asp.net

My web system retrieve the time value in DateTime type from server and I need to display it with the specific format in label text

> ```
> The time value in DateTime type retrieved from server: 00:05:23.4994656
> Display it to be : 05:23
>
> If the time value has more than 1 hour
> Time value in DateTime type: 01:05:23.4994656
> Display it to be : 01:05:23
> ```

How can I achieve it in c#?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try searching for ".NET format time" (MSDN: [Formatting type in the .NET framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy.aspx)).

Comment: If these are `DateTime` or `TimeSpan`, you can still format them to display with `.ToString` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **TimeSpan** to parse it, and check if it's `more than one Hour`, then format it:

```
TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.Parse("00:05:23.4994656");
string displayStr = "";
if (span.Hours == 0)
    displayStr = span.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
else
    displayStr = span.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```

Comment: it shows no overload for method 'ToString'takes 1 arguments

Comment: What's the type of your Application. My sample is in Windows Form or Console Application. And the type TimeSpan is under System namespace.

Comment: ASP.NET is OK. Your want to do it in aspx.cs or aspx? using C# or javascript?

Answer (score 0):

```
string theTime;
if (int.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH")) != 0)
{
    theTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
}
else
{
    theTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("mm:ss");
}
```